# How to check if a variable is equal to one string or another string?

Tags: python

```
if var is 'stringone' or 'stringtwo':
    dosomething()
```

This does not work! I have a variable and I need it to do something when it is either of the values, but it will not enter the if statement. In Java `if (var == "stringone" || "stringtwo")` works. How do I write this in Python?

Comment: I'm pretty sure both of the errors have been covered before.

Comment: for the is/== distinction : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why

Answer (score 195, accepted):

This does not do what you expect:

```
if var is 'stringone' or 'stringtwo':
    dosomething()
```

It is the same as:

```
if (var is 'stringone') or 'stringtwo':
    dosomething()
```

Which is always true, since `'stringtwo'` is considered a "true" value.

There are two alternatives:

```
if var in ('stringone', 'stringtwo'):
    dosomething()
```

Or you can write separate equality tests,

```
if var == 'stringone' or var == 'stringtwo':
    dosomething()
```

Don't use `is`, because `is` compares object identity.  You might get away with it sometimes because Python interns a lot of strings, just like you might get away with it in Java because Java interns a lot of strings.  But don't use `is` unless you really want object identity.

```
>>> 'a' + 'b' == 'ab'
True
>>> 'a' + 'b' is 'abc'[:2]
False # but could be True
>>> 'a' + 'b' is 'ab'
True  # but could be False
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This has fixed many problems in my program. :)

Answer (score 33):

```
if var == 'stringone' or var == 'stringtwo':
    do_something()
```

or more pythonic,

```
if var in ['string one', 'string two']:
    do_something()
```

Comment: @DSM missing colon, too.

Comment: Why is the second one considered more pythonic?

Comment: @RahulSharma http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/10/04/writing-idiomatic-python/ Avoid repeating variable name in compound if Statement

Comment: better yet, since you don't need it to be mutable and don't care what order they are checked in, use a set: `if var in {'string one', 'string two'}:`  It's faster, too.

Comment: @endolith This is intuitive but nonetheless fascinating to me. I've never considered this approach for more pythonic compound if-statements. For small sets, the difference is negligible, so perhaps the point is moot, but it does become significant: https://repl.it/repls/UniformLoneAiredaleterrier

Comment: @aJetHorn Actually I think tuples are faster than sets

Answer (score 7):

```
if var == 'stringone' or var == 'stringtwo':
    dosomething()
```

'is' is used to check if the two references are referred to a same object. It compare the memory address.
Apparently, 'stringone' and 'var' are different objects, they just contains the same string, but they are two different instances of the class 'str'. So they of course has two different memory addresses, and the 'is' will return False.

Answer (score 4):

Two separate checks. Also, use `==` rather than `is` to check for equality rather than identity.

```
 if var=='stringone' or var=='stringtwo':
     dosomething()
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation.I just joined StackOverflow today.

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in soup("p",{'id':'pagination'})[0]("a",{'href': True}):
        if createunicode(a.text) in ['<','<']:
            links.append(a.attrMap['href'])
        else:
            continue
```

It works for me.