# If statements in python. Does not stop the other if statements from working

Tags: python, if-statement, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle

print("Give me a shape")
shape = input()

if shape == "pentagon" or "Pentagon":
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.fd(100)
        turtle.rt(72)

if shape == "triangle" or "Triangle":
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.fd(100)
        turtle.rt(120)

if shape == "square" or "Square":
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.fd(100)
        turtle.rt(90)

if shape == "hexagon" or "Hexagon":
    for i in range(6):
        turtle.fd(100)
        turtle.rt(60)

if shape == "circle" or "Circle":
    turtle.circle(100)

else:
    print("Not a shape")
```

Comment: that is what `elif` is for

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774279/python-how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-equal-to-one-string-or-another-string

Comment: Since you're not using the value of `i` in `for i in range(...)`, I'd suggest using `for _ in range(...)`. Using an underscore as the loop variable is a common convention which emphasises that something is being repeated, and that the loop variable isn't important.

Answer (score 3):

Your check `shape == "pentagon" or "Pentagon"` is incorrect and will always be `True`, because checking string always return `True`, e.g. `bool("Pentagon")` is `True` and checking of `"pentagon" == "pentagon"` is `True`.
You should use `shape in ["pentagon", "Pentagon"]` or better `shape.lower() == "pentagon"` instead.

```
import turtle

print("Give me a shape")
shape = input().lower()  
if shape == "pentagon": 
    for i in range(5): 
        turtle.fd(100) 
        turtle.rt(72)    
elif shape == "triangle": 
    for i in range(3): 
        turtle.fd(100) 
        turtle.rt(120)    
elif shape == "square": 
    for i in range(4): 
        turtle.fd(100) 
        turtle.rt(90)    
elif shape == "hexagon": 
    for i in range(6): 
        turtle.fd(100) 
        turtle.rt(60)    
elif shape == "circle": 
    turtle.circle(100)    
else: 
    print("Not a shape")
```

Comment: Wouldn't `shape = input("Give me a shape: ").lower()` be an improvement rather than changing the case for every condition?

Answer (score 1):

Your statements like

```
shape == "pentagon" or "Pentagon"
```

evaluate to `True` or `"Pentagon"`.

You need to compare `shape` to both values:

```
shape == "pentagon" or shape == "Pentagon"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use elif statements after the first if. Alternatively you could convert your input to lower case by using '.lower'. Which would mean that you wouldn't have to have an or in the statements. It would also accept TRIANGLE for example.

```
import turtle

print("Give me a shape")
shape = input()

if shape == "pentagon" or shape == "Pentagon":
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.fd(100)
        turtle.rt(72)

elif shape == "triangle" or shape == "Triangle":
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.fd(100)
        turtle.rt(120)

elif shape == "square" or shape == "Square":
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.fd(100)
        turtle.rt(90)

elif shape == "hexagon" or shape == "Hexagon":
    for i in range(6):
        turtle.fd(100)
        turtle.rt(60)

elif shape == "circle" or shape == "Circle":
    turtle.circle(100)

else:
    print("Not a shape")
```

Comment: When I do that it does the first one and then none of the others.  For example if I type circle it will only print out the pentagon and then stop.

Comment: That is beacsue the or "Pentagon" will always be True as you aren't re-evaluating shape. Please see my edit.